# I only need the 0 value in this case from an array of [0, undefined, null, false]

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have tried the filter and find method to get the value 0 but it did not worked it just returns undefined

```
[0, undefined, null, false].filter(e => e) // output empty array
[0, undefined, null, false].find(e => e)  // output undefined
```

If anybody helps me out to find the solution for this I would greatfull for you help

Comment: Perhaps `.filter(e => e === 0)` or `.find(e => e === 0)`?

Comment: what if there is some other number instead of 0 like 1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

```js
const filtered = [0, undefined, null, false].filter(e => e === 0);
const found = [0, undefined, null, false].find(e => e === 0);

console.log(filtered);
console.log(found);
```

Comment: what if there is some other number instead of 0 like 1 or 2